# Angular component two way binding to object with http

Tags: angularjs, http, components

I have a scope object named 'formData'.

In my page, the user chooses a dataSource and with http provider I store the result to formData.

```
 $http.get($scope.options.dataSource.transport.read(id))
 .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     $scope.formData = data.value[0];
 })
 .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
 });
```

Then in my html I want to use another component passing the formData I retrieve from the http request.

```
<input-text field="Code" caption="Code" dataitem="formData"></input-text>
```

In input-text component i have

```
var inputText = {
    templateUrl: 'Input-text.tml.html',
    bindings: {
        field: '@',
        caption: '@',
        dataitem: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.field = this.field;
        $scope.caption = this.caption;
        $scope.dataitem = this.dataitem;
    }
}
inputText.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

And in Input-text.tml.html

```
{{dataitem}}
```

But this doesn't work, seems it's not working as two way binding, this is: When formData changes, the component doesn't change the `dataitem` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that `formData` is not available initially, and component gets undefined as `dataitem` binding. In controller you make assignment `$scope.dataitem = this.dataitem;` which results in `$scope.dataitem` being `undefined`. Later when http request resolves and `formData` becomes an object (array, whatever) it however is not going to update `$scope.dataitem` because there is not connection between those references. On the other hand, `this.dataitem` updates automatically.

Don't reassign `dataitem` to scope property, you don't need it:

```
controller: function () {
    // use this.dataitem directly
}
```

Drop `$scope` and use `dataitem` bound to controller. In template it will become `{{ $ctrl.dataitem.whatever }}`.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, i try without controller but still doesnt work. I is two ways bindings should update value when http result comes

Comment: Sure, `this.dataitem` updates without issue. So use `dataitem` bound to controller (`this.dataitem`), don't reassign to `$scope.dataitem`, because this will not update. I added explanation in the answer.

Comment: ok i get it, this.dataitem update automatically but $scope.dataitem not...however how can display in my html dataitem? i tried without created $scope in my html like {{dataitem}} but still not work

Comment: There is no reference between `$scope.dataitem` and `this.dataitem`. Initial assignment `$scope.dataitem = this.dataitem` won't be reassigned automatically later. That's why you need to use `this.dataitem` which is always up to date.

Comment: i tried in controller to watch this dataItem with watch.
        $scope.$watch('dataitem', function () {
            console.log(this.dataitem)
        }, true);
but doesnt work, do you know why?